# How can I tell if someone is on my home network or wifi?

Tags: security, performance, networking, wireless-networking

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to see who is using my wifi](https://superuser.com/questions/143658/how-to-see-who-is-using-my-wifi)

I have a simple home network (DSL Modem, Linksys wireless router, Vista PC, and a couple of  XBox360s).

I know that my DSL speed is annoyingly inconsistent, but recently my home network speed seems very sluggish, even for communication between the PC and XBox (I use the XBOXen as Windows Media Center extenders).

Using my meager home equipment, is there any way to tell if there are other devices on the network, slowing things down? (Pesky neighbors?) Or to tell if something else weird is going on?

Wireless is set to use WPA (Going from memory, I think that's right. Its the most secure option my router had available).
I'm also set to not broadcast the network name, you have to type in the network name and password to connect. I do use the wireless for my iPhone, and for the occasional laptop that happens to visit.

Comment: This question has already been answered: [How to see who is using my wifi](http://superuser.com/questions/143658/how-to-see-who-is-using-my-wifi)

Answer (score 3):

In the administration screen of the router, you can view currently connected devices (and normally their MAC address, too, and the assigned IP).  You can check this to see if there are more devices than you have setup.

If you are using wireless, it is more likely that the speed issue is signal interference than someone leeching your connection, especially if you have security setup.

If you tell me what model linksys I can link instructions for the admin screen in that model.

Comment: I'll have to get the model number at home. It's Blue, if that helps ;) But I think I already have instructions somewhere for getting into the admin tool.

Comment: OK good, then it should be pretty easy.  If you were able to set up the password protection you should be able to do this.  I really think the issue is going to be with interference, though, and not with leeching.  If leeching IS an issue, you can turn off SSID broadcast, which makes your network invisible unless you know the name, or you can enable MAC address filtering, which will only allow devices you explicitly list to join the network.  GOOD LUCK!

Comment: Are you talking about *wireless* interference? Because the PC and XBoxes are all connected via Ethernet, so that couldn't cause slowness there. I only use wireless for my iPhone and the occasional laptop.

Comment: Oh, if everything is wired then thats a different story.  Step 1 will be check for leeching, after that you may need to see if you have another issue with a cable or connection.  Sometimes a short in CAT5 can cause this kind of issue, too.

Answer (score 0):

you can use some future of this software
http://home.comcast.net/~jay.deboer/airsnare/

when you create a table of "friendly MAC addresses" (all your computers MAC addresses)
If new MAC address appears in your network you will be alerted.