# Strange number of computers randomly popped up on my network?

Tags: windows-7, windows, networking

I noticed a sudden change in the number of computers on my network. What is the reason for this? When I first came to this apartment complex it only showed my computer, then a couple months ago it had a couple more and today its got 22 and 17 media devices?

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Do you have a wireless network? If so, check its security settings. If it's unsecured (or only using WEP, which is basically the same as unsecured), it's possible that those computers all belong to your neighbours who are leeching off your wifi.

Comment: For more information on how to detect and deal with wifi leeching, see these questions: [How to see who is using my WiFi](http://superuser.com/q/143658/108226), [What is the most practical security method for a home wireless network?](http://superuser.com/q/3180/108226) and [How to put fear of God (law) into Wi-Fi hacking neighbors](http://superuser.com/q/405725/108226).

Comment: Unclear:  Is this your private WiFi system, or the apartment's?  If the latter then those are your neighbors just connecting to the WiFi system (though there may be questions as to how secure the setup is).  If this is your private WiFi system then those are people "stealing WiFi" from you because you did not properly secure your router.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can think of only one explanation: you have an unsecured wireless network at home and your neighbors are leeching your wifi! See Indrek's comment to look into securing your network

Answer (score 0):

if its not wifi leeching issue then one possible explanation can be the network service provider added more clients to your lan.

or you might have connected to different (Open)network all together if your pc is accessed by some other person as well, He might have done the setting.

Answer (score 0):

try opening CMD

Start 
run
CMD

and typeing Net view

and if your a global Admin you can just terrorise them but shutting down there computers and stuff using the shutdown -i command.

but on a all serious note, if you do the net view command and its shows that they are on your network, consider change your wifi password